# Is it possible to change UI of another app from my Flutter app?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make a Flutter mobile app which will have a floating button just like the facebook messenger head. When user clicks on it, my app will get all the texts from the app that's currently open, translate it, then replace the texts with the new translated texts.

Is it possible to achieve this using Flutter? or Is there a workaround to achieve the same result?